# Trying to make a bookshelf console application but having some trouble with lists. (C# Beginner)

Tags: c#, list, console-application

I am trying to make a bookshelf application but I am having trouble with using lists. What I am hoping for is after the user specifies how many books they would like to add, the for-loop should hopefully repeat the method in the specified amount.

After the first run through of the method, the more titles added will add onto the list.

```
    class Shelf
{
    public void Program()
    {
        Book book = new Book();

        int bookAmount;

        Console.WriteLine("How many books are you adding.");
        bookAmount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for(int x = 0; x <= bookAmount; x++)
        {
            AddBook(book); 
        }
    }

    public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        List<string> bookTitles = new List<string>(); 

        string bookTitle;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter title.");
        bookTitle = Console.ReadLine();
        bookTitles.Add(bookTitle);

        bookTitles = book.Title; // 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

    }
}

    class Book
{
    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

}
```

Any critique is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question... but yes, you can't convert a `string` to a `List<string>`. What did you expect `bookTitles = book.Title` to do?

Comment: Next, think about *state* - you're creating a new `List<string>` each time you call `AddBook`. You should think about an instance variable instead of a local variable... Then think about the `Book` object that you're creating... what's its purpose?

Comment: Possibly a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com, as there is no problem/question stated here. You should get it to compile first though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I am not so sure - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thats why I added the "compile first" piece. It looks like he is looking for a general critique, which is why I reccommended CodeReview. It does need to work before migration though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, but "compile" part is not enough. It should be working code.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Totally agree, I was under the impression that it was working except for that line, but could have been wrong. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want to do would be something like this:

```
public class Book
{
     public string ISBN { get; set; }
     public string Title {get; set; }
     public string Author {get; set; }
}
```

The book will represent our data model.  Now you would do this:

```
List<Book> library = new List<Book>();
int quantity;
while(quantity < 7)
{
    library.Add("12345", "C#", "Someone");
}
```

What the code is doing, we create a `List<Book>` which will hold our data model.  Then you would have a loop that iterates based on value the user inputs.  Then you would simply call the library (List) and add after it ask the user for input.

Obviously I'm not attempting to get user input or validation, but is using the example of how to use a `List`.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped greatly!

Comment: No problem, happy to help that is what our community is for.

Answer (score 0):

Following can be helpful:

```
class Shelf
{
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    public void Program()
    {
        int numberOfBooks;
        Console.WriteLine("How many books are you adding.");
        numberOfBooks = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int x = 0; x <= numberOfBooks; x++)
        {
            AddBook(); 
        }
    }

    public void AddBook()
    {
        string bookTitle;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter title.");
        bookTitle = Console.ReadLine();
        books.Add(new Book(bookTitle));
    }
}
class Book
{
    private string title;

    public Book(string _title)
    {
         title = _title;
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

}
```

Keep in mind to:

1. Assign meaningful names to variables
2. Use input arguments to methods when it is needed
3. Pay more attention to Global and Local variables and when they should be used

Comment: Thanks alot! I heard that using static variables/global variables should try and be avoided at all costs, is this correct practice?

Comment: Static/global variables, mutable classes, and `ArrayList` should all be avoided.

Comment: @DourHighArch: I don't think so, specially for *ArrayList*. It is recommended to not using them, but in some situations the best solution would be using them. These features are provided for some situations.

Comment: @RyanSwann: Your welcome, I had forced to use static and global variables in many cases. It's depend of what you want from your program. I some cases you have to use them

Answer (score -2):

I think that you must change your code like below code:

1- you must create book in addbook but you crate class in main program function

2- you can not convert string to list

3- your colcetion must contain a book

```
  class Shelf
{
    public void Program()
    {

        int bookAmount;

        Console.WriteLine("How many books are you adding.");
        bookAmount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //book is deleted
        for(int x = 0; x <= bookAmount; x++)
        {
            AddBook();//parameter was deleted and aff in function 
        }
    }
List<Book> bookTitles = new List<Book>();  //collection create generally in class like fields 

    public void AddBook()
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        string bookTitle;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter title.");
        Book.Title = Console.ReadLine();
        bookTitles.Add(book); //add book to colection
    }
}

    class Book
{
    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Any explanation? Code with no context/explanation is unlikely to be helpful to the OP.

Comment: It is not difficult to make code-only answer for some questions, and while it may solve the problem to the OP, it doesn't describe the reasons behind the problem and doesn't give any explanations or advises. So it is not very useful for future SO users. It is better to include some relevant explanation and links. And for relatively simple questions such explanations may be even more difficult to create than for more complex cases.