# When I print my lists, they are blank. Why is this?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have made a book shelf application with lists. Essentially, the user enters the amount of books they would like to add, then does so. The bottom method is the source of the problem (ListBooks). I am trying to print the lists but it prints them blank.

```
class Shelf
{
    public void Program()
    {
        List<string> bookTitle = new List<string>();
        List<string> bookAuthor = new List<string>();
        List<int> bookPageCount = new List<int>();
        List<int> bookWordCount = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("1. Add Book.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. List Book.");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Quit.");

        int userEntry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch(userEntry)
        {
            case 1:
                AddBook(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPageCount, bookWordCount);
                break;

            case 2:
                ListBook(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPageCount, bookWordCount);
                break;

            case 3:
                Environment.Exit(1);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void AddBook(List<string> bookTitle, List<string> bookAuthor, List<int> bookPageCount, List<int>bookWordCount)
    {

        string title, author;
        int bookQuantity, pageCount, wordCount, userEntry;


        Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of books you would like to add.");
        bookQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        for (int x = 1; x <= bookQuantity; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter title.");
            title = Console.ReadLine();
            bookTitle.Add(title);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter author.");
            author = Console.ReadLine();
            bookAuthor.Add(author);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter page count.");
            pageCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bookPageCount.Add(pageCount);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter word count.");
            wordCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bookWordCount.Add(wordCount);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("1. Main Menu.");
        userEntry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch(userEntry)
        {
            case 1:
                Program();
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid data.");
                Program();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void ListBook(List<string> bookTitle, List<string> bookAuthor, List<int> bookPageCount, List<int>bookWordCount)
    {

        int userEntry;

        Console.WriteLine("1. Titles.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Authors.");

        userEntry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch(userEntry)
        {
            case 1:
                bookTitle.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // Prints blank 
                break;

            case 2:
                bookAuthor.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // Prints blank
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid data.");
                Program();
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Everything seems to be in order here so I have no idea why it does this. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You really should have a `Book` class that encapsulates the data. Then you need just a `List<Book>` instead of a `List<...>` for each data member.

Comment: Why did you not use the `Book` class in the [answer you accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25333394/22437) for your previous question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep lists as class fields. Currently you have them as local variables, and they are initialized each time you enter `Program()` method:

```
class Shelf
{
    List<string> bookTitle = new List<string>();
    List<string> bookAuthor = new List<string>();
    List<int> bookPageCount = new List<int>();
    List<int> bookWordCount = new List<int>();

    public void Program()
    {
       // removed from here
    }
}
```

NOTE: Recursive `Program()` calls is a bad idea. Here it just complicates program logic, and at some point you will end with `StackOverflowException` because you will get very deep in recursive calls. Use loop around main menu switch instead. You should remove `Program()` calls from other methods and use infinite loop:

```
public void Program()
{
    List<string> bookTitle = new List<string>();
    List<string> bookAuthor = new List<string>();
    List<int> bookPageCount = new List<int>();
    List<int> bookWordCount = new List<int>();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add Book.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. List Book.");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Quit.");

        int userEntry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (userEntry)
        {
            case 1:
                AddBook(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPageCount, bookWordCount);
                break;
            case 2:
                ListBook(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPageCount, bookWordCount);
                break;
            case 3:
                Environment.Exit(1);
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want improve your code further, then create book class, which will hold all book data

```
public class Book
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
   public int PageCount { get; set; }
   public int WordCount { get; set; }
}
```

Keep single list of these objects instead of four different lists.

Comment: Yep, now you got it :)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault thanks :) At first glance I thought OP is creating new instances of default `Program` class, but after little investigation I saw that `Program` is a method name)

Comment: Thanks you so much! I saw you changed your reply several times to get it right so thank you for that, really appreciate the help. Using the infinate loop for this bit should help fix some other things I am working on as well.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - very nice example!  +1 fo sho